# Extjs Set Combobox value when Init Controller Method is load

Tags: extjs, combobox, controller, store

i am new using Extjs 4.2.1. I have a main controller where i want to SET a combobox initial value when Init method is load. I had did this:

```
init: function(){

var suc =  Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ListaSucursales');
//suc.load();
console.log(suc.getCount());

}
```

I had noticed that this store has 0 items. It means that the store was not loaded althought its autoLoad property is true. So my question is. Where i must Set the combobox initial value using the controller.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the combobox value on store load like this:

```
   store.load({
         callback:function(records, operation, success){
             // set combo value
         }
    });
```

Comment: Dear @user1896597: thank you for your reply. But... It's not the goal that controller must this kind of settings? By the way, if my store has the property autoLoad... this will work too?

Comment: Not sure why your autoload isn't working. Just as a test you can do this:  `code`store.on('datachanged', function() {
             //alert('store loaded')
         });`code`